# Check if push notification sent using Parse - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am current sending push notification from the client device using Parse. I am using the following code to achieve it.

```
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();//mobile2
                pushQuery.whereEqualTo("userName", message.getText().toString());
                ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                Log.e("", "" + pushQuery.toString());
                push.setQuery(pushQuery);
                try {
                    JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"message\": \"The Mets scored!\",\"sound\": \"cheering.caf\"}");
                    push.setData(data);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                push.sendInBackground();
```

Is there a way to check if the push notification was sent successfully or not ? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I am asking in the device, how do I know whether the request to send Push notification was made successfully or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can check this out in Parse's admin console. Login and go to Push tab and you can see push notifications sent, how many devices received it and how many times it was opened.

Comment: I am asking in the device, how do I know whether the request to send Push notification was made successfully or not ?

Comment: One way to test it, you could be one of the recipients and see if you get it, but that's only to test if parse is initialized correctly. Otherwise, I don't think you can recieve like a reponse "successfully sent" because parse will try multiple times to send it in the background to multiple devices. Some may recieve it, some may not.

Comment: Thats not a good approach. I dont want the sender to receive the same content. It would be too clumsy.

Comment: I know the approach is bad and I was thinking of only using it when testing. Once the setup is tested it should not fail sending, but I believe I know what you wish to achieve and I don't know if it's possible to get a feedback from parse.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found a solution.
Try `push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback{...});`

Comment: I've edited my comment, a bit fast on my enter key, please let me know if it works. :)